Spring BootのValidationの前処理をしたい。
入力項目の入力内容について「半角英数のみ○桁以内」というようなValidationチェックを行う前に、「Excelの結合セルからのコピペ(後タブ付き)」や「HTMLページからのコピペ(前空白付き)」といった入力に対してValidation前にそのような空白文字の除去を行いたいです。
Formのフィールドにアノテーションを付けて特定の項目に、このような前処理を行うことは可能でしょうか？
リゾルバを試してみましたが動きませんでした。
public class SpaceTrimMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

  @Override
  public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
    return parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(SpaceTrim.class);
  }

  @Override
  public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
    String parameterValue = webRequest.getParameter(parameter.getParameterName());
    return parameterValue != null ? parameterValue.trim() : null;
  }

  public @interface SpaceTrim {
  }
}


@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
    resolvers.add(new SpaceTrimMethodArgumentResolver());
  }
}

Adviceではアノテーションのチェックができませんでした。
@ControllerAdvice
public class SpaceTrimControllerAdvice {
  @InitBinder
  public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new SpaceTrimEditor());
  }

  class SpaceTrimEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) {
      if (text == null) {
        setValue(null);
      } else {
        setValue(text.trim());
      }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
      Object value = getValue();
      return (value != null ? value.toString() : "");
    }
  }
}


フォーマッタで実現可能だと思います。
アノテーションの定義は、対象がフィールドのみなら下記のようになります。
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface SpaceTrim {
}

アノテーションをトリガーとしてフォーマッタを適用したいので、AnnotationFormatterFactory の実装クラスを作成します。
ここではカスタムの Formatter も含めて定義していますが、独立したクラスとして定義しても問題ありません。
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.format.AnnotationFormatterFactory;
import org.springframework.format.Formatter;
import org.springframework.format.Parser;
import org.springframework.format.Printer;

public class SpaceTrimFormatterFactory implements AnnotationFormatterFactory<SpaceTrim> {
  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getFieldTypes() {
    return Set.of(String.class);
  }

  @Override
  public Printer<?> getPrinter(SpaceTrim annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {
    return new SpaceTrimFormatter();
  }

  @Override
  public Parser<?> getParser(MyAnno annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {
    return new SpaceTrimFormatter();
  }

  private static class SpaceTrimFormatter implements Formatter<String> {
    @Override
    public String print(String object, Locale locale) {
      // テンプレートへの出力時の処理（この例ではそのまま出力）
      return object;
    }

    @Override
    public String parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
      // パラメータバインド時の処理（要件に応じて書き換えてください）
      return text == null ? null : text.trim();
    }
  }
}

WebMvcConfigurer#addFormatters() 経由で作成した AnnotationFormatterFactory を登録します。
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
  @Override
  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
      registry.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new SpaceTrimFormatterFactory());
  }
}

標準のバリデーション用アノテーションと併用することもできます。
public class MyForm {
  @Size(max = 100)
  @SpaceTrim
  private String text;
  // ...

なお、リクエストハンドラーで @RequestBody を使っている場合はフォーマッタではなく、カスタムの JsonDeserializer を使う必要があるようです。

とてもわかりやすい、丁寧な回答ありがとうございます。
